# how to find number of days between columns (A6 - contact date & A7 - response date)

Tags: sql-server

Receive error when execute in SQL.

```
SELECT viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A3 AS STNum, viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A6 AS DateofRef
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A6b AS TimeofRef
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A7 AS InitRespDate
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A7b AS InitTime
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A8a
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A8c
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A8d
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A8e
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A8f
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A8g
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A8h
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A8i
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A8j
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A8k
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A8l
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.L2a AS Gen             
SELECT datediff(dd, A6, A7) AS WAITTIME           
FROM viewz_INTAKE_STACK 
INNER JOIN RAI_RAI ON viewz_INTAKE_STACK.rai_uno = RAI_RAI.rai_uno      
WHERE (Where A6 BETWEEN $P{FromDate} and $P{ToDate})ISNULL(A6, '1900-01-01')!='1900-01-01'
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my query?

Comment: What error did you get? In addition to the suspect line 6, I think you want ` AND ` in the `WHERE` clause before `ISNULL`.

Comment: is the second select supposed to be a sub query? You have duplicate `where` sitting out there too

Comment: Hi Dan, Here is the error - Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Where'.

Answer (score 0):

If you would have formatted it as Dale did for you, you could see that you have a nested select statement. This part:

```
SELECT datediff(dd, A6, A7) AS WAITTIME           
FROM viewz_INTAKE_STACK 
INNER JOIN RAI_RAI ON viewz_INTAKE_STACK.rai_uno = RAI_RAI.rai_uno      
WHERE (Where A6 BETWEEN $P{FromDate} and $P{ToDate})ISNULL(A6, '1900-01-01')!='1900-01-01'
```

If this is supposed to be a sub-query, it'd need to be wrapped in parentheses.

Additionally, for your outer query, there is no `FROM` clause.

So, as a guess, you probably just want to remove the second `SELECT` word and add a comma for the column, remove the one instance where you only called the base table and no column, and remove the duplicate `where`. Here's a stab at it.

```
SELECT 
    viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A3 AS STNum
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A6 AS DateofRef
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A6b AS TimeofRef
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A7 AS InitRespDate
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A7b AS InitTime
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A8a
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A8c
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A8d
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A8e
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A8f
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A8g
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A8h
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A8i
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A8j
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A8k
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.A8l
  , viewz_INTAKE_STACK.L2a AS Gen             
  , datediff(dd, A6, A7) AS WAITTIME           
FROM viewz_INTAKE_STACK 
INNER JOIN RAI_RAI ON viewz_INTAKE_STACK.rai_uno = RAI_RAI.rai_uno      
WHERE A6 BETWEEN $P{FromDate} and $P{ToDate} and ISNULL(A6, '1900-01-01')!='1900-01-01'
```

Comment: Thx scsimon. When i run your query it gives this error - Msg 126, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Invalid pseudocolumn "$P".

Comment: Well you need to replace that in your where clause with whatever your date column is.